# Can I show steps of solution while solving a PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

I can see step by step solution while solving an ODE by Wolfram Mathematica Pro. Can I also see the solution steps of PDEs?

Example:

```
WolframAlpha["D[y[x, t], t] + 2 D[y[x, t], x] == 0"]
```

Comment: Mathematica itself does not include such functionality. It seems you are using Wolfram Alpha, and the question is really independent of Mathematica (you could do the very same in the browser, without Mathematica).  Pure Wolfram|Alpha questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: `Trace[DSolve[D[y[x, t], t] + 2 D[y[x, t], x] == 0, y, {t, x}],TraceInternal -> True]` will show the (principal) *Mathematica* steps, but, being a computer program with lots of parsing, error and consistency checking, *Mathematica* makes many, many steps.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: There's also ``Block[{DSolve`print = Print}, DSolve[D[y[x, t], t] + 2 D[y[x, t], x] == 0, y, {t, x}]]``, fwiw.